# Get parent property which is a table from a child in titanium

Tags: javascript, dom-events, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have a checkbox as a button and have added it to table's row view. How to access the row index by using the checkbox. Sample code is like below. The `EmpList[i]` I get it from another function.

```
var createTablerow = function(){
var empSelectView = Ti.UI.createView({
     width : '30%',
     height : '100%',
     layout : 'vertical',
     id: EmpList[i].empID
 });
 
var typeCheckBox = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage: 'images/uncheck.png',
    id: EmpList[i].empID,
    checked:false,
    width: 25,
    height: 25,
    left: 5,
    right: 5,
    top:15
    });
    
  empSelectView.add(typeCheckBox);
  labelView.add(empSelectView);
  labelView.add(empNameView);
  rowView.add(labelView);
  
 typeCheckBox.addEventListener('click',function(e){
if (e.source.checked == true){
    e.source.image = 'images/uncheck.png';
    e.source.checked = false;
    var index = empDelList.indexOf(e.source.id);
    var selRowId = deleteIndexList.indexOf(e.index);
    if (index > -1) {
        empDelList.splice(index, 1);
        deleteIndexList.splice(selRowId, 1);
    }
} else {
    e.source.image = 'images/check.png';
    e.source.checked = true;
    empDelList.push(e.source.id);
    deleteIndexList.push(e.index);
        }
  });
}
```

How to access `e.index` of the table inside the listener of `typeCheckBox` which is a child of the table row. In the `deleteIndexList` Array I want to push the table index that are selected.

Comment: If your children count is same for all tableViewRows then simply addEventListener on tableView and get (e.index) of table and to change the images to 'check' or 'uncheck' you can get it by going upto that children and changing the image.

Comment: @swanand thanks a lot..that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add an [click](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-event-click) event listener to the TableView (which gives you the `index`) and then look at the `source` property of the event to determine if the user tapped on the button.